# reorder a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've come across the problem: what is the best way to reorder this array using PHP:

```
Array { 
      Array[0]
      (
        [car_1] => 'Toyota',
        [car_2] => 'Camry',
        [car_3] => 'Mazda',
      ),
     Array[1]
      (
        [car_1] => 'Mustang',
        [car_2] => 'Camry',
        [car_3] => 'Dodge',
        [car_4] => 'Ram',

      ),
    Array[2]
      (
        [car_1] => 'Mustang',
        [car_2] => 'Camry',
        [car_3] => 'Eclipse',
        [car_4] => 'Acura',
       )
}
```

The resulting solution should be:

```
 Array ( 
        [car_1] => 'Toyota',
        [car_2] => 'Camry',
        [car_3] => 'Mazda',
        [car_4] => 'Mustang', 
        [car_5] => 'Dodge',
        [car_6] => 'Ram',
        [car_7] => 'Eclipse',
        [car_8] => 'Acura',

       )
```

I'm not sure how to reorder the array indexes like they are achieving in the result:

```
function array_reorder($arry)
{ 
    $reordered_arry = array();
    $size = sizeof($arry);        //the outer loop:
    for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++){
        if($i == 0){
            array_push($reordered_arry,array_filter($arry[$i]));
        }
        else{
            //the inner array loop

            foreach(array_filter($arry[$i]) as $key_outer =>$value_outer){ 
                print_r($arry[$i]);
                foreach($reordered_arry[0] as $key=>$value){
                    //print_r('value outer is'.$value_outer.'value inner is:'.$value.'<br>');
                    //print_r($reordered_arry[0]);
                    if($value_outer == $value) { 
                        unset($reordered_arry[0][$key]);
                    }else {
                        // array_push($reordered_arry,$value_outer);
                    } 
                }
            }
            return $reordered_arry;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: All you need to do is to create a result array, then iterate over your multi-dimensional array adding only those cars that do not already exist in the result array.

Comment: Why use car_* key naming approach? It is going to makes working with you data a pain.  Without it, you could just merge your sub arrays.Consider numerically indexed array. You also haven't commented on your strategy for deduping values.

Comment: I agree this problem is out of a book of difficult to solve PHP problems so im just going by what they have, it would obv be easier with numeric indexs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`RecursiveArrayIterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php) class.

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr));
$new_arr = array();$i=1;
foreach($it as $v) {
    if(!in_array($v,$new_arr))
    {
    $new_arr['car_'.$i]=$v;
    $i++;
    }
}
print_r($new_arr);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [car_1] => Toyota
    [car_2] => Camry
    [car_3] => Mazda
    [car_4] => Mustang
    [car_5] => Dodge
    [car_6] => Ram
    [car_7] => Eclipse
    [car_8] => Acura
)
```

[<kbd>Working Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/128772)

Comment: great job i didnt think to use the recursiveiterator